# How to detach an Azure classic NSG from a classic VM?

Tags: azure, networking, azure-virtual-machine

In azure classic, I have a classic network security group attached to a classic virtual machine.
I cannot delete the NSG because it is associate to a VM, but I don't see any option to detach the NSG from the VM neither I find a PS or CLI command to detach the NSG from the VM.
Do I need to delete the VM to delete the NSG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could Power Shell to disassociate the NSG and delete it.

```
$vm=Get-AzureRmResource  -ResourceId "/subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourceGroups/shuiclassic/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/shui" -ApiVersion "2017-04-01"
$vm.Properties.networkProfile.networkSecurityGroup=""
 $vm|Set-AzureRmResource -Force
```

You also could do it on Azure Portal.

[image]

Then Click your NSG and select None.

[image]

Click `Save`, then you could delete this NSG.